# Postgres query GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, odoo

please help me with this query

```
SELECT
   quant.id AS id,
   quant.product_id AS product_id,
   quant.location_id AS location_id,
   quant.qty AS qty,
   quant.lot_id AS lot_id,
   quant.package_id AS package_id,
   quant.in_date AS in_date,
   quant.company_id,
   prod.default_code,
   template.categ_id AS categ_id
FROM stock_quant AS quant
JOIN product_product prod ON prod.id = quant.product_id
JOIN product_template template ON template.id = prod.product_tmpl_id
WHERE quant.company_id = 1
AND location_id = 12
```

I want to group the results by `prod.default_code` or `quant.product_id`

Here is a screenshot a sample of result. I want the sum of quantity
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: And which of the many result rows for a certain `prod.default_code` do you want to get?

Comment: Try to use GROUP BY at the end of query but returns me ```ERROR:  column "quant.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function```

Comment: Every field that are in the select must appear in the group by or you have to use an aggregation function like (max, min, avg...) on the fields that shouldn't be grouped. For example if two rows have same `default_code` value but different `id` => it doesn't know which id has to appear once (= be grouped).
Or maybe what you just want is `ORDER BY default_code` ?

Comment: Here is a screenshot. I want to GROUP BY ```product_id``` or ```default_code```
[link](https://ibb.co/ZBsnqPT)

Comment: Show us your expected output @panosdotk

Comment: Add a screenshot to my first question @Flo

Comment: @flo, No, I want the sum of this 5 lines to 1 line with quantity = 80. Sorry, I can't answer to your post

Comment: Do the column "id, product_id, location_id...." have to appear ? Or you just want a default_code, product_id, sum_of_quantitiy ?

Comment: A result with only two columns (```default_code``` & ```qty```) will be fine. But I want the sum of quantities. (qty=80)

Comment: @panosdotk edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the column `default_code, product_id, sum_of_qty` then you can do this  :

```sql
SELECT
   prod.default_code,
   quant.product_id AS product_id,
   SUM(quant.qty) AS sum_of_qty
FROM stock_quant AS quant
JOIN product_product prod ON prod.id = quant.product_id
JOIN product_template template ON template.id = prod.product_tmpl_id
WHERE quant.company_id = 1
AND location_id = 12
GROUP BY prod.default_code, product_id
```

If you need `default_code` only or `product_id` only, just remove the unnecessary field from both `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`.